# SwifUI : Is my downloaded JSON saved to coreData?

Tags: json, core-data, swiftui

I've been messing around with CoreData and this time I'm trying to save my downloaded JSON to core data. I don't get any error until I try to display the list and it would return empty.
Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Model

```
struct ArticleData: Identifiable, Decodable {
    let id : String
    let type : String
    let attributes: ArticleAttributee
    
    struct ArticleAttributee: Codable {
        let name: String
        let card_artwork_url: String
        ...
    }
```

AttributeArticle+CoreDataProperties.swift

```
extension AttributeArticle {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<AttributeArticle> {
        return NSFetchRequest<AttributeArticle>(entityName: "AttributeArticle")
    }

    @NSManaged public var card_artwork_url: String?
    @NSManaged public var content_type: String?
   ...

    public var wrapperCard_artwork_url : String {
        card_artwork_url ?? "Unknown"
    }
    ...
}
```

Download JSOn and load to Core Data

```
class Article {
    
    static func loadDataFromJSON(completion: @escaping ([ArticleData]) -> ()) {    
        let stringURL = "https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5ed679357741ef56a566a67f"
        
        guard let url = URL(string: stringURL) else { return }
        
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {
            data, response, error in
            
            guard let data = data else {
                print("No data in response \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No data response")")
                return
            }
            
            if let decoderLoadedUser = try? JSONDecoder().decode([ArticleData].self, from: data) {
                
                completion(decoderLoadedUser)
                
            }
        }.resume()
    }
    
    
    
    static func loadDataToCD(moc: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        loadDataFromJSON { (articles) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                
                var tempArticles = [AttributeArticle]()
                for article in articles {
                    
                    let newArticle = AttributeArticle(context: moc)
                    newArticle.name = article.attributes.name
                    newArticle.card_artwork_url = article.attributes.card_artwork_url
                    ... so on
                    ...
                    tempArticles.append(newArticle)
                }
                do {
                    try moc.save()
                } catch let error {
                    print("Could not save data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

my list :

```
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    
    @FetchRequest(entity: AttributeArticle.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var articles: FetchedResults<AttributeArticle>

VStack {
        List() {               
            ForEach(articles, id: \.id) { article in
               NavigationLink(destination: ArticleDetailView(articles: article)){
                   ArticleRowView(articles: article)
                   }
               }
            }
         }.onAppear {
            if self.articles.isEmpty {
                print("Articles is empty \(self.articles)")
                Article.loadDataToCD(moc: self.moc)
            }
```

Sorry for the long post and thank you for your helps!

Comment: You don't get an error because you ignore the Decoding error. There is one.

Comment: thank you, I fixed and the list is shown. Thank you for point that out for me!